# Find All permutation of String using Iteration

Tags: algorithms, strings

How to find all permutation of a String in Iterative way ?

### Code (Recursion) :

```
private void permute(String str, int l, int r)
{
    if (l == r)
        System.out.println(str);
    else
    {
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
        {
            str = swap(str,l,i);
            permute(str, l+1, r);
            str = swap(str,l,i);
        }
    }
}


public String swap(String a, int i, int j)
{
    char temp;
    char[] charArray = a.toCharArray();
    temp = charArray[i] ;
    charArray[i] = charArray[j];
    charArray[j] = temp;
    return String.valueOf(charArray);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Knuth shows how to do it in his *Art of Computer Programming*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia describes several algorithms, including:

- [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm).
- [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm).

Comment: Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations

Answer (score 0):

You can use the algorithm in the link below:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutations-string-using-iteration/

Comment: Perhaps you can, at the very least, type the algorithm here?

Comment: that page says: "How to print all permutations iteratively?
A simple solution to use permutations of n-1 elements to generate permutations of n elements." Isn't that recursion?